# How we can find $y$ in $xAy =b.$

Tags: linear-algebra

How we can solve the following equation for  $y$, knowing that $A$ is an antisymmetric, non degenerate $(n \times n)$ matrix, when given:  $$ x A y =b$$

Comment: What is $x$? A vector?

Comment: If x and y are vectors $xAy$ (ie $x^TAy$) is a scalar.

Comment: yes exactly, $x$ and $y$ are vectors, $A$ is antisymmetric and inversible matrix, $b$ scalar. Knowing $A, b$ and $x$ (or $y$), I want find $y$ (or $x$).

Comment: @nesrineYOUSFI Your question is similar to finding a solution to $a_1 y_1 + a_2 y_2 = c$ presuming $x$ and $b$ are known and $x$ is a row vector.

Comment: Yes it's true, but I want solve for such matrix without having it explicitly. I mean, if I give the size and and the components of $A$ I can solve it. But I want such solution like for $Ax=y$ then $x= A^{-1}y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ Ay=v$ and sole for $x^Tv=b$ This equation has the form of $$ x_1v_1+x_2v_2+...x_nv_n=b$$ which normally has infinitely many solutions. Now you want to solve $Ay=v$ for $y$. This is a system of $n$ equations in $n$ variables. If solvable, you find solutions for y.

Comment: Riazi Kermani Thank you.

Comment: Welcome and have a good rest of the day